# Importing gradle project in AndroidStudio fails

Tags: android, eclipse, import, gradle, android-studio

I've got a win8 64bit computer.
I downloaded android studio, exported from eclipse my project as gradle build.
Then I wanted to import in AndroidStudio, but it always fails with the following message:

> Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\Develop\gradle'.
>
> Build file 'D:\www\DiLocSyncMobile\native\android-debug\build.gralde' line: 9
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root proect 'android-debug'.
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-debug'.
>
> The SDK directory 'C:\Applications\adt-bundle-mac\sdk' does not exist.
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I tried nearly everything (downloaded gradle, added it to the path, delete .gradle folder in user directory, etc.

But nothing helped..
Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your SDK directory is not set correctly. In fact, it seems as though it is set to the mac android developer tools.

I would suggest lookings at your local.properties file (or creating one if it is not already in the root of your project) and making sure that it has the following line:

```
sdk.dir=<path to your android sdk>
```